# Alternative of xdmp:functions() in MarkLogic 5.0?

Tags: marklogic

Is there any API to get all in-scope functions in MarkLogic 5.0?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do with more detail.

Comment: User will save xquery snippets like cq. Use case is to find out all function names from snippet and tag them while saving snippets.

Comment: Do you mean all function names including everything included by default (all cts:*, xdmp:*, etc.) or just the functions called or defined in the snippet? `xdmp:functions()` would return the former. For the latter you would need to do some kind of static analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your response.xdmp:functions() is right for my requirement but it's not available in ML 5.0. I am going with Regex approach for time being.

Comment: You could also take a look at the profiling API. That may work as a shortcut to reducing the snippets down a sequence of expressions. From there it should be less messy to regex.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned there is no direct API in ML5. I would discourage a regex approach: XQuery needs to be parsed. But a debugger-based approach could work. Take a look at https://github.com/robwhitby/xray/blob/coverage/src/coverage.xqy for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

can you not query the docs?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

let $doc := xdmp:http-get("https://docs.marklogic.com/5.0/all",
    <options xmlns="xdmp:http-get">
       <format xmlns="xdmp:document-get">xml</format>
    </options>)[2]

let $table := $doc/node()//xhtml:table[@class="api_table"]

return $table//xhtml:td/xhtml:a/fn:string(.)
```